# How to make a part of HTML file not updated under a certain condition

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

I have a HTML file which is updated every 30 seconds. It is rendered by Jinja2 from a certain python file to pass variables. Is there any way to omit updating of some elements?

The code looks like that:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My site</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
<style>

b.value {
position: absolute;
border: 2px solid black;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
}

.head {
position: absolute;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<b class="value" style="left:920px;">{{ var1 }} %</b></h2>
<h3 style="padding-left:860px;padding-top:200px;"> Text 2: under me is the part I want to update only when the condition is true</h3>
{% if var2 != 0 %}
   <b class="head" style="padding-left:900px;">{{ var2 }}</b>
{% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

I want to refresh the variable *var2* only if it is not equal to 0 and not every 30s, as the rest of page is updated.

Thank you for the tips,
Kaki

Comment: Did the above script not working for you ?

Comment: Well, the script above only shows the variable var2 when it is not equal to 0. If it is 0, there is nothing displayed. In that case I would want to display the "old" value.

Comment: See my below answer, in which I have added else section

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

wich basically tells the browser to refresh the page in 30 seconds you cannot specify certain elements that should or should not be refreshed.

The refresh is nothing other then hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> and the webpage has no controll over it.

If you want to dynamically reload certain elements use AJAX with javascript.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So if I understand it right, you cannot do that with flask/ python ? I would have to solve this before passing the variable, which would be comfortable with the auto refresh.

Comment: You could do that with python / flask but it would be way more difficult because you would need to manage sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding else section. See if the below code works for you.

```
{% if var2 != 0 %}
   <b class="head" style="padding-left:900px;">{{ var2 }}</b>
{% else %}
   Do something here
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The code works, I am just not able to address the previous value of var2, because I don't want to display the var2=0 value. Thank you for the attempt.

Comment: @Kaki when it comes in else section that means it will have value other than 0.

Comment: actually there is != sign, so that means the else section is executed only if the value is equal to 0.

Comment: Yeah right. Sorry I didn't notice.

Comment: Well you can display the previous value of var2 by creating global variables in your python script. in which you can save the new and previous value.

Comment: Yeah. According to Simon Kirsten answer, I will have to do it like that.